# Ruby, sort array of hashes passed by the an specified hash key

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, key

I want to sort an array of hashes by a passed hash key that is specified as a parameter:

```
array([{'a' => 2}, {'a' => 1}], 'a') => [{'a' => 1}, {'a' => 2}]]

array([{a: 1}, {a: 5}, {a: 3}], :a) => [{a:1}, {a: 3}, {a: 5}]
```

Thanks

Comment: the example provided is sorting by values and not keys

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every hash will have the specified key?  If not, what should be done with those that do not have the key?

Comment: You could clarify your question by including other keys in your examples (assuming my understanding is correct).  For example: "for the array [{a: 2, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 3}, {a: 3, b: 2}], if the parameter is :a, the desired result is [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 1}, {a: 3, b: 2}].  If the parameter is :b, the desired result is [{a: 2, b: 1}, {a: 3, b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 3}]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def array(arr, key)
  arr.sort_by { |a| a[key] }
end
```

Comment: does not answer the OP's question, the OP here is sorting by values not keys, the question is also very ambigious

Comment: @bjhaid, I think this is what the asker wants to do: for a given key, sort the array by the values of that key.